# CMSEncodeContent failed with errSecNoSuchKeychain (-25294)

Tags: macos, cryptography

I have a program which works with OSX Security framework. I start my program in two modes.

In the first mode the program calls several Security framework functions:

1. calls SecPCS12Import function and successfully imports a certificate with a private key and creates an identity ref.

   ```
       CFStringRef passwordRef = CFStringCreateWithCString(0, password.c_str(), kCFStringEncodingUTF8);
       const void *keys[] = { kSecImportExportPassphrase, kSecReturnRef };
       const void *values[] = { passwordRef, kCFBooleanTrue };
       CFDictionaryRef optionsDictionary = CFDictionaryCreate(0, keys, values, 2, 0, 0);
       CFDataRef inPKCS12Data = CFDataCreate(0, (const UInt8*)data.data(), data.size());
       CFArrayRef items = 0;
       OSStatus status = SecPKCS12Import(inPKCS12Data, optionsDictionary, &items);
       CFRelease(passwordRef);
       CFRelease(optionsDictionary);
       CFRelease(inPKCS12Data);

       throwIfError(errSecSuccess != status);

       CFDictionaryRef myIdentityAndTrust = (CFDictionaryRef)CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(items, 0);
       SecIdentityRef identity = (SecIdentityRef)CFDictionaryGetValue(myIdentityAndTrust, kSecImportItemIdentity);
       KeyInfo info(alias, OSStoreImplementation::getCertificate(identity));
       IKey::Ptr result = new OSKey(info, new OSKeyImplementation(identity, false));
       CFRelease(items);
       return result;
   ```
2. calls CMSEncodeContent with the identity ref getting on previous step and successfully signs a message.

   ```
       CFDataRef content = 0;
       CMSSignedAttributes signedAttributes = kCMSAttrSmimeCapabilities | kCMSAttrSmimeMSEncryptionKeyPrefs;
       throwIfError(errSecSuccess == CMSEncodeContent(_identity, 0, 0, FALSE, signedAttributes, message.data(), message.size(), &content));
       char* buf = (char*)CFDataGetBytePtr(content);
       const ByteArray result(buf, buf + CFDataGetLength(content));
       CFRelease(content);
       return result;
   ```

after all the program ends.

In the second mode the program makes some another list of calls:

1. calls SecCertificateCreateWithData with the certificate in DER format corresponding the private key from the first start of the program and successfully creates a certificate ref.
2. calls SecIdentityCreateWithCertificate with the certificate ref got in the previous step and successfully creates an identity ref.

   ```
       CFDataRef content = CFCreateData(0, info.certificate.getData().data(), info.certificate.getData().size());
       SecCertificateRef cert = SecCertificateCreateWithData(0, content);
       CFRelease(content);
       SecIdentityRef identity = 0;
       OSStatus status = SecIdentityCreateWithCertificate(0, cert, &identity);
       CFRelease(cert);

       throwIfError(errSecSuccess != status);

       KeyPtr result = new OSKey(info, new OSKeyImplementation(identity, true));
       CFReleases(identity);
       return result;
   ```
3. calls CMSEncodeContent with the identity ref getting on previous step and fails to sign a message with errSecNoSuchKeychain (-25294). Source code absolutely the same as in the first mode of the program.

How can I fix this bug and why this error happens every time when I start my program in the second mode?

Comment: To sign you need a private key. You say you create a certificate in the "second mode", but where is the private key?

Comment: The documentation of SecIdentityCreateWithCertificate function says: If the associated private key is not found in one of the specified keychains, this function fails with an appropriate error code (usually errSecItemNotFound), and does not return anything in the identityRef parameter. But you right problem in this function. I think that I found a solution.

Answer (score 0):

I rewrite my code in second mode. I change SecIdentityCreateWithCertificate on SecItemCopyMatching.

```
        CFDataRef content = CFCreateData(0, info.certificate.getData().data(), info.certificate.getData().size());
        SecCertificateRef cert = SecCertificateCreateWithData(0, content);
        CFRelease(content);
        const void* data[] = { cert };
        CFArrayRef secItemOrArray = CFArrayCreate(0, data, 1, 0);
        const void *keys[] = { kSecClass, kSecReturnRef, kSecMatchItemList };
        const void *values[] = { kSecClassIdentity, kCFBooleanTrue, secItemOrArray };
        CFDictionaryRef attributes = CFDictionaryCreate(0, keys, values, 3, 0, 0);
        SecIdentityRef identity = 0;
        OSStatus status = SecItemCopyMatching(attributes, (CFTypeRef*)&identity));
        CFRelease(attributes);
        throwIfError(errSecSuccess != status);
        KeyPtr result = new OSKey(info, new OSKeyImplementation(identity, true));
        CFReleases(identity);
        return result;
```

New version works correctly. So I found solution which do what I need, but I still don't understand why my previous code didn't work.